# How many trucks can line up in one dock outside a speakeasy?

Tags: bootleggers

Each speakeasy has 3 docks (majority, minority, and public), but within each of those docks/bays, how many trucks are allowed to queue?  For example, say there is a speakeasy with 4 minority holders (no majority), can each holder put a truck in the minority (two star) loading dock?

The space on the board between the front of the speakeasy and the placeholders for Men of Action cards is only [big enough to comfortably fit 2](http://cf.geekdo-images.com/images/pic930927_md.jpg).  But there is nothing in the rules (as far as I could see) which limited the number of trucks allowed in each dock.

Comment: ps I don't know what tags to use.  I did see that "rules" was deprecated, but I didn't know what else to use and I'm not yet of high enough rep to create my own tag for Bootleggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm going to risk making the obvious answer.  There is nothing in the rules which limits the number of trucks allowed in each dock... probably because there is no limit to the number of trucks allowed in each dock.

Looking at this example paragraph in the rulebook (p11):

> b. If the demand has not been fulfilled, the Speakeasy must continue
>   buying Crates from the Truck(s) at the Minority Dock, again paying the
>   Wholesale Purchase Price to the Crate supplier.  The Trucks are lined
>   up in Muscle card order, so Mobsters with higher Muscle cards are more
>   likely to sell their Crates.  Any Crates in excess of demand go unsold
>   and are lost.

Truck(s) clearly implies that there can be multiple trucks at the Minority
Dock.  All the stuff about lining trucks up in Muscle card order suggests to
me, albeit more vaguely, that there can be quite a few trucks there.  If there were only 2 trucks allowed at the Minority Dock, you'd expect some kind of phrasing such as "the Mobster with more Muscle cards", rather than "Mobsters with higher Muscle cards", wouldn't you?

Comment: We did play it as though you could have as many trucks as you like.  But I also spent 10mins during play reading and re-reading the rules trying to find a definitive answer.  I wondered if anyone else ever had the same question.

Comment: It would certainly have been nice of them to specify that there is no limit on the number of trucks in a queue... if their decision to allot only two "spaces" to each queue was, as I suspect, purely to cut the costs of printing a larger board!